# yo: command not found (Mac 10.9.4); no previous solutions work

Tags: node.js, macos

Yeoman and bower do not work at all. I installed node using the Mac node package downloaded from the nodejs site.

npm: 1.4.21 / node: v0.10.30

.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export M2_HOME=/Users/cmorrow/apache-maven-3.1.1
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/cmorrow/npm/lib/node_modules:$PATH
```

I installed yo with:

```
npm install -g yo
```

The post install reads:

```
yo@1.2.1 postinstall /Users/cmorrow/npm/lib/node_modules/yo
node ./scripts/doctor
[Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks alright!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure the exact fix, but I made a few changes and everything now works.

Things I did were:

**Upgraded node js to v0.10.31**

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

**Reinstalled yeoman**

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

Comment: In case anybody in the future stumbles across this and thinks it's a good idea...don't do it. Get npm installed correctly so you don't have to run with sudo an have permission issues later. http://www.wenincode.com/installing-node-jsnpm-without-sudo/
and https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689 if you happen to have any issues with the first

Answer (score 0):

If you install nodejs by HomeBrew he manually create a symbolic link in the folder

```
/usr/local/bin
```

if the manually installation don't generate that symbolic link you can doing manually with this command (with sudo):

```
ln -s /Users/cmorrow/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js /usr/local/bin/yo
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/yo
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually didn't install with Homebrew, but tried an install of Homebrew which showed me conflicting symlinks. I deleted the symlinks, upgraded node, and reinstalled yeoman. Things are working now. Still learning symlinks and how all this works.